# How to query all user with Kinvey in iOS with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, kinvey

This is the sample code to query for users within Kinvey, however if I don't input specific information I get errors. How do I query for all users (in Swift)?

```
    //Find all the Smiths
    KCSUserDiscovery.lookupUsersForFieldsAndValues(
[ KCSUserAttributeSurname : "Smith" ],
completionBlock: { (objectsOrNil: [AnyObject]!, errorOrNil: NSError!) -> Void in
    if errorOrNil == nil {
        //array of matching KCSUser objects
        NSLog("Found %d Smiths", objectsOrNil.count)
    } else {
        NSLog("Got An error: %@", errorOrNil)
    }
},
progressBlock: nil
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of users by reading directly from the `Users` collection. The code below shows how you can do that -

```
        let collection = KCSCollection.userCollection()
        let store = KCSAppdataStore(collection: collection, options: nil)

        store.queryWithQuery(KCSQuery(), withCompletionBlock: { (objectsOrNil: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            //objectsOrNil is a list of users 
        }, withProgressBlock: nil)
```

Note that permissions on your user collection may protect certain users from appearing in your results.